# Visual Studio 2012 view webpages in mobile devices

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a plugin for VS2012 that will allow me to view my MVC4 pages as in mobile device? Some sort of emulator.
thanks

Comment: I love [responsible layout](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)!

Comment: @SteveB: You mean ... responsive ?! ;-)

Comment: :p At least someone read my comment! Yes. I mean responsive layout.

Comment: @SteveB http://sixrevisions.com/mobile/responsive-web-design-not-the-future/

Comment: @F1beta: interesting point of view. Arguments of the author are very receivable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a responsive page/layout, I would choose a responsive framework like [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/).
There's a [nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/Twitter.Bootstrap), even if I would download the css and javascript and implement it myself. 
It's quite easy to grasp and you can find lot of tutorials.

If what you're asking is a tool which can allow you to test and render your asp.net MVC app in a mobile device you can try [opera mobile emulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/mobile-emulator).

Comment: more info http://www.refactorthis.net/post/2012/08/14/Emulating-iPhone-iPad-and-Opera-devices-to-debug-mobile-ASPNET-MVC4-apps-with-VS-2012-and-WebMatrix-2.aspx